# Integration with 2 related variables

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, substitution

If  $$y(x-y)^2 = x.$$

Then $$\int \frac{1}{x-3y}  \, dx =? $$

How do I go about doing This?

Just if you want to know the options are in the form of log{(x-y)² + 1}

[This  may not be the answer as this is just one of the options,  Its just to get an idea]

Hints will do.

Comment: see the beautiful answer from Hardy http://math.stackexchange.com/a/943545/72031

Comment: @ParamanandSingh Thank  you,  beautiful indeed!